# remove all words after character / including it

Tags: r

I have this list of elements  that I've called with the name row

```
 row <-

    [[798]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-Deu"

    [[799]]
    [1] "Simple/repeat"

    [[800]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-Deu"


    [[802]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-gip"

    [[803]]
    [1] "Simple/repeat"

    [[804]]
    [1] "SINE/MIR"

    [[805]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-Deu"

    [[806]]
    [1] "Simple/repeat"

    [[807]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-Deu"

    [[808]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-Deu"

    [[809]]
    [1] "SINE/tRNA-Deu"

    [[813]]
    [1] "Low_complexity/alfa"
```

there is a way to eliminate all the words after / in all the elements? 
I've tried this:

```
row1 <- gsub("(/).*", "\\1", row)
```

but in the output the character "/" is not deleted. I don't wanto to include it in the name of elements ( ex. SINE, Simple, etc.):

```
[1] "SINE/" "Simple/" "SINE/" "SINE/" "Simple/"

[6] "SINE/" "SINE/" "Simple/" "SINE/" "SINE/"

[11] "SINE/" "Low_complexity/"
```

Where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix, don't use a capture group:

```
row1 <- gsub("/.*", "", row)
```